# Add legend for abline to ggplot geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to add a legend, that only describes the lines in my plot, which is similar to this one:

```
library(ggplot)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1:10), seq(from=2, to=20, 2)))
ggplot(data=df, aes(V1, V2))+geom_point()+
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1)
```

I only want to add the abline to the legend. I already tried to work with geom_line, but it vanishes when I adjust the x and ylims of the plot. ggplot2 does not have the option to build a legend from scratch similar to lattice, does it?[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the geom_abline parameters in an `aes()` and add a color element, which is then controlled in the `scale_color_manual()` call:

```
   ggplot(data=df, aes(V1, V2)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_abline(aes(color="whatever", intercept=0, slope=1)) +
      scale_color_manual(values = "red") +
      labs(color=NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it for both different colours:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(color="red", V1, V2)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="blue")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(color=NULL)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeEDf.jpg)

Comment: Thank you,Now I have the line in my legend.However, now there are three lines in my legend; one for the abline and two for the groups of the data points. Is it possible to turn the lines for the datapoints into a pch of choice? In my case 16.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a completely customed legend using grid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829284/ggplot2-manually-add-a-legend