# Resize and move manual grob legend ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I have a ggplot2 object that I'm trying to add a legend for some vlines. I followed the following:([ggplot2: manually add a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829284/ggplot2-manually-add-a-legend)) but I was unable to get my desired output. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Where I got to:

[image]

My desired output is to place the manual legend directly above the Species legend (or below it)

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(grid)  
library(gtable)
library(dplyr)

plot2 <- iris %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., nrow = 3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6, y = 4.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "darkblue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 7, y = 4.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") 

L1 = linesGrob(x = unit(c(.5, .5), "npc"), y = unit(c(.25, .75), "npc"),
               gp = gpar(col = "black", lty = "longdash"))
L2 = linesGrob(x = unit(c(.5, .5), "npc"), y = unit(c(.25, .75), "npc"),
               gp = gpar(col = "darkblue", lty = "longdash"))
T1 = textGrob("line 1 explaing something", x = 0, just = "left")
T2 = textGrob("line 2 explaing something", x = 0, just = "left")

leg = gtable(width = unit(c(1,5), "cm"), height = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
#leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA, col = "black")), t=2,l=1,b=4,r=2)

leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, L1, t=2, l=1)
leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, L2, t=3, l=1)
leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, T1, t=2, l=2)
leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, T2, t=3, l=2)

g = ggplotGrob(plot2)

pos = g$layout[grepl("panel", g$layout$name), c('t', 'l')]
g = gtable_add_cols(g, sum(leg$widths), pos$l[1])
g = gtable_add_grob(g, leg, t = pos$t[1], l = pos$l[1] + 1)
g = gtable_add_cols(g, unit(6, "pt"), pos$l[1])

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

I also tried this approach:

```
vlines <- data.frame(line = c("Line 1 Explaining Something", "Line 2 Explaining Something"), 
                     y = c(4.5, 4.5), x = c(6, 7))

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., nrow = 3) +
  geom_linerange(data = vlines, 
                 aes(x = x, 
                     ymax = y,
                     ymin = 0,
                     color = line),
             linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_linerange(data = vlines, 
                 aes(x = x, 
                     ymax = y,
                     ymin = 0,
                     color = line),
             linetype = "dashed")
```

But as you can see it doesnt add the dash and it combines it with the other line type...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to achieve the desired output is to use `new_scale_color` function from `ggnewscale` package to set a new color legend for the vertical lines.

In my solution, I also replace the use of `geom_linerange` by `geom_vline` that allow to draw vertical lines just by specifying the x intercept values.

With your example, you can draw something like that:

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(Species ~ ., nrow = 3) +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_vline(data = vlines, 
             aes(xintercept = x, color = line), linetype = "dashed")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","black"), name = "")
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: thanks, yeah i used geom_linerange b/c there was an open issue with geom_vline in github that seemed related to this issue so i thought it might be a work around. This is great, much appreciated!

Comment: Ok I was not aware of this issue. Anyway, glad that my answer helps you :)